# INSERT Performance - Bitmap vs B-Tree

Tags: database, oracle, b-tree, bitmap-index

If we put the select performance aside, which one is faster when it comes to insert. I couldn't find any thorough explanation for this. Can someone please explain? This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9541541/b-tree-vs-bitmap-database-indexes) just labels bitmaps as inefficient but I want to know why.

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bitmap indexes can be problematic for inserts if there is contention. If you have a single thread doing the inserts they are fine, but if there are multiple threads doing inserts and perhaps updates and deletes they tend to limit performance due to locking.

A single key in the index may point to a large number of records, so when the index is changed many rows are locked.

As a general rule, go for normal indexes. In special cases bitmap indexes can shine - normally for read-mostly applications rather than OLTP systems.

Comment: This totally makes sense. thanks for quick response mate